# Convert List< Guid > to List< Guid? >

Tags: c#, linq, casting

What is the best practice to convert List< Guid > to List< Guid? >

The following does not compile:

```
public List<Guid?> foo()
{
    List<Guid> guids = getGuidsList();
    return guids; 
}
```

Comment: where's the difference between "List< Guid? > to List< Guid? >"? can't see it...

Comment: I think he meant `List<Guid?>` -> `List<Guid>`

Comment: Not sure how how saying `List<Guid> guids = (from... select...);` does not compile is going to show us what you have tried. Of course it won't compile.

Comment: @voo, [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) is structure.

Comment: @DanielKelley : That part was irrelevant. I removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this

```
return guids.Select(e => new Guid?(e)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 16):

The question seemed to change a couple times, so I'll show the conversion both ways:

Convert `List<Guid?>` to `List<Guid>`:

```
var guids = nullableGuids.OfType<Guid>().ToList();
// note that OfType() implicitly filters out the null values,
// a Cast() would throw a NullReferenceException if there are any null values
```

Convert `List<Guid>` to `List<Guid?>`:

```
var nullableGuids = guids.Cast<Guid?>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public List<Guid> foo()
{
    return  foo.Where(x=>x != null).Cast<Guid>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: the return type should be `List<Guid>`.

Comment: the return type should be List<Guid?>

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<Guid?> foo()
{
    List<Guid> source = getGuidsList();
    return  source.Select(x => new Guid?(x)).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:

```
public List<Guid> foo()
{
    return foo.Where(g => g.HasValue).Select(g => g.Value).ToList();
}
```